# Decimal(s, p) no guarda la cantidad suficiente de digitos

Tags: sql-server

Quiero en mi tabla de base de datos poner una columna de tipo decimal que permita guardar 4 números antes de la ',' y 2 números después de ella.

Ejemplo:

```
    1234.45
    1567.89
```

Para esto cree esta tabla de prueba:

```
CREATE TABLE numeros(
    numero DEC(4,2)
);
```

pero al realizar una inserción en la tabla me permite ingresar números hasta el 99

Comment: Hasta el 99 en qué parte?

Comment: Es que  debes definir la columna como `decimal(6,2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Porque entendiste mal la documentación.

```
decimal[ (p[ ,s] )]
```

donde p es la cantidad **total** de digitos, y s es la cantidad de **ellos** que son decimales.

Entonces, `DEC(4,2)`, quiere decir que va a haber 4 digitos, y dos de ellos seran decimales.

[fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)